# Pyspark how to filter a dataframe inside RDD Map Function?

Tags: python, pyspark

Im trying to query a dataframe inside a map callback function and create a new column with a calculation based on multiple rows and columns.

DF looks like this

| datum | start | uhrzeit | quittierung |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | XYZ | 08:00:00 | 2021-01-01 09:00:00 |
| 2021-01-01 | XYZ | 07:05:00 | 2021-01-01 09:05:00 |
| 2021-01-01 | XYZ | 07:05:00 | 2021-01-01 09:05:00 |
| 2021-01-01 | XYZ | 10:00:00 | 2021-01-01 10:05:00 |
| 2021-01-01 | XYZ | 10:00:00 | 2021-01-01 11:00:00 |

```
df = SPARK_DATAFRAME

def func1(x):
    count = df.filter(df.datum == x.datum).filter(df.start == x.start).filter(df.uhrzeit < x.uhrzeit).filter(df.quittierung[12:19] > x.uhrzeit).count()
    return (x.datum, x.start, count)



rdd2=df.rdd.map(lambda x: (func1(x))) 
df2=rdd2.toDF(["datum", "start", "count"])
df2.show()
```

By doing this i get the following error message:

> PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects

Can someone help me how i can archieve expanding the original dataframe by some columns where the value is based on a query over the complete dataframe?

Example Result

| datum | start | uhrzeit | quittierung | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | XYZ | 08:00:00 | 2021-01-01 09:00:00 | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 | XYZ | 07:05:00 | 2021-01-01 09:05:00 | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 | XYZ | 07:06:00 | 2021-01-01 09:05:00 | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 | XYZ | 10:00:00 | 2021-01-01 10:04:00 | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 | XYZ | 10:05:00 | 2021-01-01 11:00:00 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need `df.groupby("datum", "start").count().show()` wouldn't that give you the result you are looking for? Or do you really need to use `rdd.map`?

The reason for the error is that spark tries to serialize the function `func1` however inside the `func1` you have the original dataframe, which is not serializable.

Comment: For simplicity i removed a part of the filtering concatenation. By that i think i missed crucial detail. Actually  I do not only need to filter for equal values where groupby would do the trick but also make comparisons. Do you know how to do it without RDD? I tried the pandas workaround but the calculation takes too long.

Comment: Could you give an example resulting dataframe?

Comment: I edited the orignal post

Answer (score 1):

You could try with a group by and an Pandas UDF like the following:

```
df = SPARK_DATAFRAME

@pandas_udf(df.schema, functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def func1(pdf):
    count = pdf.loc["same filtering but in Pandas"].count()
    return (count)


Result= df.groupBy(['datum', 'start']).apply(func1)
```

Something in this direction should work